# Odoo/OpenERP Add Sales Order Line Product_ID via XML-RPC PHP

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc

Ok so I am trying to pass a Odoo sales order with sales order lines using the XML-RPC and PHP.
It work perfectly... Except I cannot pass a product_id

so this works...

```
      $lines[] = new xmlrpcval(
                                 array(
                                         new xmlrpcval(0, 'int'),
                                         new xmlrpcval(0, 'int'),
                                         new xmlrpcval(
                                        array(
                                                'name'            => new xmlrpcval('Product Name', 'string'),
                                                'product_uom_qty' => new xmlrpcval(5, 'int'),
                                                'price_unit'      => new xmlrpcval(10.00, 'double'),
                                                'sub_total'       => new xmlrpcval(50.00, 'double'),
                                        ),
                                        "struct"
                                )
                        ),
                "array"
        );
      $arr = array(
        'partner_id'          => new xmlrpcval(236,"int"),
        'partner_invoice_id'  => new xmlrpcval(236,"int"),
        'partner_shipping_id' => new xmlrpcval(236,"int"),
        'client_order_ref'    => new xmlrpcval($this->id,"int"),
        'order_line'          => new xmlrpcval($lines, "array"),
      );
var_dump($arr);
       $client = new xmlrpc_client($this->server."object");
        $client->return_type = 'phpvals';
        //   ['execute','userid','password','module.name',{values....}]
        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->database, "string"));  //* database name */
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->uid, "int")); /* useid */
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->password, "string"));/** password */
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("sale.order", "string"));/** model name where operation will held * */
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));/** method which u like to execute */
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($arr, "struct"));/** parameters of the methods with values....  */
        $resp = $client->send($msg);
        if ($resp->faultCode()){
        echo 'failed';
        var_dump($resp);
            return -1; /* if the record is not created  */
        }else{
        echo 'success';
        var_dump($resp);
            return $resp->value();  /* return new generated id of record */
    }
```

So to attach the products correctly (match the products in the openerp/odoo database) I need to pass the product ID...

So if i add to the array the following line...

`'product_id'      => new xmlrpcval(38, 'int'),`

I then get an error like the follow...

```
warning -- MissingError

One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.
```

Not sure what im doing wrong but this is driving me insane!
And I've checked that product id 38 exists!

Many, many, MANY thanks in advance!!

Comment: Maybe you should search the product with XML-RPC to be sure the product ID is the good ID and exists in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Your product_id is wrong. To make sure, export your product to csv, and then check it from settings-->external identifier & sequences. See what is your product record id.

Comment: Thanks, may of worked. Think i solved this over a year ago, no needed anymore. Someone else may find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `product_id` in `intval`